# Unable to start Gauge Intellij plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, import

I am new to android and have been following udacity android course. I was asked to install a existing android project from github on doing so I am getting following error.

Unable to start Gauge Intellij plugin.Could not find executable in `PATH`. Please make sure Gauge is installed. If Gauge is installed then set the Gauge executable path in settings -> tools -> gauge.

What is gauge? How can I solve this error and start working on the project??

I already installed gauge

Maybe the problem is with path here it is I am not getting how to set this path

Answer (score 2):

In the android studio `settings -> tools -> gauge` give `GUAGE_HOME` path variable which is

**Windows**

`%ProgramFiles%\gauge\bin`

**macOS**

`/usr/local/bin`

**linux**

`/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 2):

I was able fix this by uninstalling and re-installing gauge plugin in IntelliJ 2020.1.3

Answer (score 0):

In the Android Studio go **`File → Plugins → Marketplace`**. Search for `Gauge` and install it.
[image: Gauge plugin]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. Basically the problem was I did not entered the path variable value and GAUGE_HOME variable value in setting->tools->gauge.

Comment: where is the path located ? I cant find it anywhere